# Why is Hana the only person credited for uniting Suzuran?

Tags: crows, worst

It's been a long time since I have read Crows, but from what I understand, Bouya Harumichi pretty much did the exact same thing as Hana Tsukishima, and arguably even better than Hana.

Hana's team lost to Manji and Hana lost to the strongest Manji guy, Bisuko. Whereas Bouya was able to defeat his Manji counterpart. Sure, Bouya was sort of the lone wolf at Suzuran, but when push came to shove, he was able to rally the entire school to follow him. I'm just kind of confused why despite his legendary status, Bouya wasn't given credit for also uniting Suzuran.

Answer (score 1):

The differences between them did not lie in their strength as a fighter. Most agree that both of them were strong, some would even argue that Harumachi was stronger.

The differences were all about what they did outside of fighting itself. Where even their intent of fighting have a nuanced difference.

- This would be a recurring theme and an important point, Harumachi's attitude was to care for a group of friends (which he didn't really admit to either). Tsukishima's was to care for everyone (which basically is the crux of everything). To do that, he set out to be the boss of Suzuran.
- One of the most important differences was that Tsukishima set out to be Suzuran's boss, but Harumachi didn't, in fact the opposite, in that he knew that he was the strongest there but steadfastly refused to be called a boss. While that may seem trivial, it is the very essence of the question you posed - that Hana wanted to be a boss and became one while Harumachi rejected the title.
- Another difference was the makeup of the school while they were considered to be "boss" (Using it loosely as Harumachi wasn't a "boss"). While Harumachi was there, there were many competing factions ("gumi") that were there and they had their issues with each other, fights, etc. They weren't united. They might fight together for a common cause, like the time Harumachi managed to mobilise the school, but when they came back, it went back to normal.
- Compare this to when it was the Hana-Gumi. All "Gumi"s were either absorbed or "beaten" such that they were following the Hana-Gumi. Consider the FBI, were even though they didn't merge, they formed a shadow force that followed the Hana-Gumi's will.
- Tsukishima probably had more charisma, in the way he carried himself and was some sort of moral compass for everyone. He naturally was well liked and drew people to him, and he welcomed them and always helped everyone out, even strangers. Compare this to Harumachi just trying to get his way with his fist. No doubt both succeeded, but perhaps, the way it was done was one of those differences people look for in a leader, a boss, in the self declared hell-hole of the area.

Perhaps there are many more differences, but I think I tried to cover the most major points that would shed light on why. Technically, there was no explicit reason given by the author, but that was because I think he was trying to **show** the difference and have you make up your own mind.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's mainly because Bouya never claimed the title of Boss or even fought for the title, whereas Hana fought to become the Boss.

Comment: Can you point out some evidence from the series that supports this?